# Linq cast conversion Xelement error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, xml, linq, casting, linq-to-xml

I'm attempting to parse an XML document as follows:

```
var locs = from node in doc.Descendants("locations")                              
select new
{
    ID = (double)Convert.ToDouble(node.Attribute("id")),
    File = (string)node.Element("file"),
    Location = (string)node.Element("location"),
    Postcode = (string)node.Element("postCode"),
    Lat = (double)Convert.ToDouble(node.Element("lat")),
    Lng = (double)Convert.ToDouble(node.Element("lng"))
};
```

I'm getting the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.

When I check the value of node I'm getting all the elements from the locations children properly, but it doesn't want to break it up for me. I've checked errors similar to this but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to convert elements or attributes to double. Simply cast them to double:

```
var locs = from node in doc.Descendants("locations")
           select new
           {
               ID = (double)node.Attribute("id"),
               File = (string)node.Element("file"),
               Location = (string)node.Element("location"),
               Postcode = (string)node.Element("postCode"),
               Lat = (double)node.Element("lat"),
               Lng = (double)node.Element("lng")
           };
```

Linq to Xml supports explicit [cast operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx).

And yes, `XElement` does not implement `IConvertable` interface, thus you can't pass it to `Convert.ToDouble(object value)` method. Your code will work with passing node value to `Convert.ToDouble(string value)` method. Like this:

```
Lat = Convert.ToDouble(node.Element("lat").Value)
```

But again, better simply cast node to `double` type. Or to `double?` (nullable) if it is possible that you can have missing attribute or element in your xml. Accessing `Value` property in that case will raise `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Use the casts, that's what it's there for.

Comment: +1 - I did not know about the explicit cast operators... Learn something new everyday

Answer (score 2):

Are you not simply missing the `.Value` property

```
                  var locs = from node in doc.Descendants("locations")

                  select new
                  {
                      ID = Convert.ToDouble(node.Attribute("id").Value),
                      File = node.Element("file").Value,
                      Location = node.Element("location").Value,
                      Postcode = node.Element("postCode").Value,
                      Lat = Convert.ToDouble(node.Element("lat").Value),
                      Lng = Convert.ToDouble(node.Element("lng").Value)
                  };
```

Comment: Odd, I tried that before and it didn't work, it must have been an error on my part. Thank you for response.

Comment: That works as long as every element is there, otherwise the OP would get null reference exception(s) trying to get the Value property.